# runtime error due to sock_open failure TPM-Emulator

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tpm

I've recently setup and installed (after much finicking around to get around the seemingly common SSL error) the Mario Strasser TPM emulator.
Setting it up to run with modprobe tpmd_dev and then tpmd worked fine, however, once it was running I wanted to begin working on some code to interact with it and ran the test_tddl file, only to find that it fails to open the /dev/tpm file. after a little digging around I've found that it's a failure due to a `sock_connect()` call fails. Have I gone wrong with setting up the emulator somewhere? I'm running on ubuntu 16.04 on a virtual box VM

The error given upon running test_tddl is `Error: Tddli_Open() failed: operation failed (0002)`
and the error given in dmesg is`Error: sock_connect() failed: -2`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your problem, you need to extract and provide a [mcve]. However, I think you'd better file a bug ticket. Be prepared to provide the steps required to reproduce the problem though.

Comment: Hmm if you set it up with the simulator, why is it trying to open `/dev/tpm`? Look at the compile options, there is probably something that tells it whether to use the simulator or not.

Comment: If you cannot make it work, you might want to have a look at [swtpm](https://github.com/stefanberger/swtpm). It's a simulator for both TPM1.2 and TPM2.

Answer (score 0):

Im an idiot, if anyone else runs into this problem, ensure that your running both `tpmd` and `test_tddl` as root, or else the programs will be unable to open the socket required.